# NLog Inserting the Log only first time

Tags: c#, nlog

I ran into a strange issue with NLog. The code i am using inserts record into the database only the first time LogMigrationInfo() is called. Then it just passes the method, no row is inserted and no error aswell. It was working fine yesterday. Not sure what is the issue. Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks

Here is my code to initialize the database logging using Nlog.
[image]
And below is the method to log the messages.
[image]

Comment: Maybe enable [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) and verify that expected connection-string values are being used. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting (Ex. ensure correct NLog.config is deployed)